# onDataChange is getting called twice in android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is My simple query for firebase data using timestamp in android app

```
Query recentStaticJobQuery = reference.child(AppConstants.WORKINDIA_JOBS)
                        .child(AppConstants.WORKINDIA_STATIC_JOBS)
                        .orderByChild(AppConstants.TIMESTAMP)
                        .startAt(lastStaticJobSyncTime); 
recentStaticJobQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent
(staticJobDownloadListener);


 ValueEventListener staticJobDownloadListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("Firebase", "Called")
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.i("Firebase", "onCancelled")
    }
};
```

How to avoid onDataChange to get called twice in android Firebase?

Comment: Is `recentStaticJobQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent
(staticJobDownloadListener);` called twice by any chance?

Comment: No. that I have tested first

Comment: If you see the `onDataChange()` of a single-value-event-listener being called twice, make sure that you're not attaching the listener in two places.

Comment: Hi! Can you show the whole code for your activity where you're attaching and detaching listeners?

Perhaps, you're attaching in onResume and in Firebase Auth in auth events as well?

Comment: @Slava Sorry I removed firebase now but I am was using recentStaticJobQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent
(staticJobDownloadListener);  so it should get called only once

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 scenarios where this may happen:

1. `onDataChange` is called twice in case you have enabled offline persistence. Once with the stale offline value and again with the updated value in case it has changed.
2. `onDataChange` is called multiple times in case you have not removed the listener properly and are creating a new instance of your listener in your activity every time you open it.

Scenario 2 is easy to fix. You can maintain local references of your firebase reference and listener, than you can do a `ref.removeListener(listener)` in `onDestroy` of your Activity. Scenario 2 is difficult to fix and you have 2 possible remedies:

1. Disable offline persistence in case you always want the updated latest value.
2. Do a `runnable.postDelayed(callbackRunnable, 3000);` to wait for the latest value for 3 seconds before updating the views or whatever you want to update.

Answer (score 3):

Use SingleEventListener instead of ValueEventListener Like this

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("YOUR-URL-HERE/PATH/TO/YOUR/STUFF");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
       // do your stuff here with value
   }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
   }
});
```

Comment: single value event defeats the purpose of using the childEventListener or valueEventListner. The purpose we're using them is to keep getting updates when there is required change in server data. Our issue is, for one single same change in server data, these listeners are getting called twice. So there is no point in using singleValueEvent, cos i get updates only once when i add the listener, not whenever the data changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your query by adding `endAt()` like below. It will help you.**

```
Query recentStaticJobQuery = reference.child(AppConstants.WORKINDIA_JOBS)
                        .child(AppConstants.WORKINDIA_STATIC_JOBS)
                        .orderByChild(AppConstants.TIMESTAMP)
                        .startAt(lastStaticJobSyncTime).endAt(lastStaticJobSyncTime+"\uf8ff");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason for this issue.

Attaching and detaching the listeners were fine. Add listener getting called only once. But still child changes and value changes were getting called twice.

I noticed that the 2nd trigger was always about 320ms after the first one. The data was same in both the callbacks, except for the fields with `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. These fields also had about 320ms increase in the 2nd trigger.

The data I was writing to the firebase database was containing the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` as it stores the server's current timestamp in that field, and I was using it to filter the data.

On removing this field from the object I'm writing to database; the listeners are getting called only once.

Here is my code that **caused 2 triggers**:

My class

```
@Entity
class Route {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = ""
        @Exclude
        get() {
            return field
        }
        @Exclude
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }
    ....
    ....
    @Ignore
    var z: Any? = null
}
```

In the viewModel

```
fun addRoute(routeName: String){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if(!repository.isRouteExists(routeName)){
                val route = Route()
                route.name = routeName
                route.addedBy = uid
                route.z = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                repository.insertRouteToFirebase(route)
            }
        }
    }
```

In the repository

```
fun insertRouteToFirebase(route: Route){
        val database = Firebase.database
        val myRef = database.getReference("routes")
        val routeId = myRef.push().key
        if(routeId != null){
            route.id = routeId
            myRef.child(routeId).setValue(route)
        }
    }
```

Logs when using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` (Notice the 300ms difference in log time and field z in data):

```
2022-09-11 11:38:05.880 23911-23911/com.slvt.vikku.sharadhamohotsav D/MY_FIREBASE: onDataChange: DataSnapshot { key = routes, value = {-NBf9NKGpmwWZDfp9uLp={addedBy=VLdrj1JbJhb1T9GXBm9WONhs5l03, name=new route , z=1662876484946}} }
2022-09-11 11:38:06.173 23911-23911/com.slvt.vikku.sharadhamohotsav D/MY_FIREBASE: onDataChange: DataSnapshot { key = routes, value = {-NBf9NKGpmwWZDfp9uLp={addedBy=VLdrj1JbJhb1T9GXBm9WONhs5l03, name=new route , z=1662876485282}} }
```

So the solution to this must be found out. This is just the cause of the issue.
On changing

```
route.z = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

to some other number like

```
 route.z = 791456
```

the listeners were getting called only once.