# firebase on Data Change is called multiple times in add value event listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have set two listeners

1. Query to get the last message
2. If the last message is group type I'm getting group info using group Listener

However, when I get the type from the message using messageListener and set groupListener it returns multiple onDataChange 
`Debug.e("parentsnap",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());` gets called more than one times
How should I do it, please guide

```
    groupListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Debug.e("parent snap", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            for (DataSnapshot d :
                    dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           //my code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    groups.child(chatId).addValueEventListener(groupListener);
```

Comment: My observations shows that addValueEventListener gets called as much as the number of changed childs.

Comment: Check out my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73677221/7042992 The 2nd trigger in my case was due to ServerValue.TIMESTAMP in the data.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to receive data one time you need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)` instead of
`addValueEventListener(...)`. Then `onDataChange()` will return only one time

Comment: I tried `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` but it doesn't return the correct value

Comment: @rookieDeveloper if it return the incorrect value => your query is wrong. it is a different problem.

Comment: wrong as in not the updated valued but which has been previously set

Comment: you should know that if you use `addValueEventListener(...)` => onDataChange(...) will call whenever you change your firebase data. And if you use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)`, `onDataChange(...)`will call only one time

Comment: I have added the listener to a specific node will it still get called every time?

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

and now test without it.

If you are persisting data locally and using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)`, it can cause multiple(2) calls to get fresh data.

Answer (score 1):

This removing of listener need not be only on activity/fragment life cycle, it must be handled even if you are on the same activity/fragment and call the addValueEventListener again on click of a button.  If the listener is already active and you start another one both the listeners are active and you get duplicate/multiple results.  It took me some time to understand this basic concept.  Here is how I do it..

**Declare Your Variables**

```
private ValueEventListener getGroupListListener;
private Query getGroupListQuery;
```

**Call Your Function**

```
getGroupListFromFireBase("0");
```

**Define Your Function**

```
private void getGroupListFromFireBase(final String hiddenStatus) {

    removeListeners();

    getGroupListQuery = fbDbRefRoot.child("groups")
                                   .child(fUserId)
                                   .orderByChild("hidden")
                                   .equalTo(hiddenStatus);

    getGroupListListener = getGroupListQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                lGroupsList.clear();
                // Do Stuff Here

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

**Remove Listener Function**

```
// Remove The Listeners
private void removeListeners() {

    lGroupsList.clear();

    // Remove Listeners
    if (getGroupListListener != null & getGroupListQuery != null) {
        getGroupListQuery.removeEventListener(getGroupListListener);

    }

}
```

**Reattach Listeners Function**

```
// Re Attach The Listeners
private void reAttachListeners() {

    // Re Attach The Listeners
    if (getGroupListListener != null & getGroupListQuery != null) {
        getGroupListQuery.addValueEventListener(getGroupListListener);

        rvGroupList.setAdapter(aGroupList);

    }

}
```

I have given the Reattach Listener function just in case you want to use these in onPause (Remove Listeners) and onResume (ReAttach Listeners) - onPause and onResume work in both activities and fragments.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when using a `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` to automatically refresh Firestore data in a `RecyclerView` in Android.

I just wanted to emit a `Boolean` each time the data changed, to show or hide an empty data message in the view ("No data found; try changing your filter.") by means of a `LiveData` which is backed by an RX subject.

The problem is that `onDataChanged()` was being invoked twice after every query change, so I needed a way to coalesce these 2 values into a single value, and only use the latest of the two values.

I already had a LiveData backed by an RX observable, so simply adding a `buffer(2)` and a `map()` made it easy to coalesce.

```
class MyViewModel : AndroidViewModel() {

    /**
     * Indicates whether or not an empty state message should be displayed.
     */
    val noMatchingDataLiveData: LiveData<Boolean> by lazy {
        noMatchingDataSubject
            // Ignore the first value
            .skip(1)

            // Only emit after every 2 items, since each data change from the adapter emits 2 messages
            .buffer(2)

            // Only emit the most recent of the 2 items
            .map { it.last() }

            .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)

            // Transforms an RX observable to a LiveData via LiveDataReactiveStreamsKt
            .toLiveData()
    }

    /**
     * The backing subject for [noMatchingDataLiveData].
     */
    private val noMatchingDataSubject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault<Boolean>(false)

    /**
     * The recycler view adapter.
     */
    internal val myRecyclerAdapter: FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<MyWidget, MyWidgetViewHolder> by lazy {
        object : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<MyWidget, MyWidgetViewHolder>(...) {

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(group: ViewGroup, i: Int): MyWidgetViewHolder {
                return MyWidgetViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(group.context).inflate(R.layout.my_widget_item, group, false))
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(
                holder: MyWidgetViewHolder,
                position: Int,
                model: MyWidget) {
                ...
            }

            override fun onDataChanged() {
                // Note that each time the query is changed, this is invoked twice:
                // The first invocation always has 0 items, because the offline cache was just cleared
                // The second invocation will have the number of items matching the query, when the offline cache is updated

                // Our subject uses a buffer to only emit every-other item
                noMatchingDataSubject.onNext(this.itemCount < 1)
            }

            override fun onError(e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenarios where this may happen:

1. `onDataChange` is called twice in case you have enabled offline persistence. Once with the stale offline value and again with the updated value in case it has changed.
2. `onDataChange` is called multiple times in case you have not removed the listener properly and are creating a new instance of your listener in your activity every time you open it.

Scenario 2 is easy to fix. You can maintain local references of your firebase reference and listener, than you can do a `ref.removeListener(listener)` in `onDestroy` of your Activity. Scenario 2 is difficult to fix and you have 2 possible remedies:

1. Disable offline persistence in case you always want the updated latest value.
2. Do a `runnable.postDelayed(callbackRunnable, 3000);` to wait for the latest value for 3 seconds before updating the views or whatever you want to update.