# Android Firebase ChildEventListener called twice

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my chat app, I want to get every new message someone send (LAST MESSAGE).

However when I attach `ChildEventListener` in my app, `onChildAdded()` is called twice.

Here is the code:

```
 chatRoomLastMessageUpdateReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
                        child(Constants.FIRE_BASE_PATH_CHAT_ROOMS).child(roomKey);
 chatRoomLastMessageChildListener = mChatHelper
        .getLastMessage(mAdapterChat, chatRoomLastMessageUpdateReference, mRecyclerChat);
 chatRoomLastMessageUpdateReference
        .addChildEventListener(chatRoomLastMessageChildListener);
```

Here is method `getLastMessage()`:

```
 public ChildEventListener getLastMessage(final AdapterChat mAdapterChat, final DatabaseReference pollRoomLastMessageUpdateReference, final RecyclerView mRecyclerChat) {

        Query queryLastMessage = pollRoomLastMessageUpdateReference.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);

        ChildEventListener childEventListener = queryLastMessage.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                Log.d("message", "onChildAdded: " + message.getMessage());
                mAdapterChat.updateLastMessage(message);
                mRecyclerChat.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(mAdapterChat.getMessagesObekt().size() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return childEventListener;
    }
```

and here is `ChildEventListener` detach:

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatRoomLastMessageChildListener != null) {
            chatRoomLastMessageUpdateReference.removeEventListener(chatRoomLastMessageChildListener);
        }
    }
```

This is Log in `onChildAdded()` method which is called after user send new chat message. I have send 3 messages and as you see every message is called twice

```html
05-29 09:55:38.000 30212-30212/com.example.petar.votemeup D/message: onChildAdded: called message1
05-29 09:55:38.001 30212-30212/com.example.petar.votemeup D/message: onChildAdded: called message1
05-29 09:55:40.382 30212-30212/com.example.petar.votemeup D/message: onChildAdded: called message2
05-29 09:55:40.384 30212-30212/com.example.petar.votemeup D/message: onChildAdded: called message2
05-29 09:55:42.954 30212-30212/com.example.petar.votemeup D/message: onChildAdded: called message3
05-29 09:55:42.955 30212-30212/com.example.petar.votemeup D/message: onChildAdded: called message3
```

**UPDATE UPDATE**

Funny fact is when I do not attach ChildEventListener, then everything is fine.
But, I do not understand now, how will I detach ChildEventListener if I do not attach it.
So, when I do this way, everything is fine

```js
   chatRoomLastMessageUpdateReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
                        child(Constants.FIRE_BASE_PATH_CHAT_ROOMS).child(roomKey);
                chatRoomLastMessageChildListener = mChatHelper.getLastMessage(mAdapterChat, chatRoomLastMessageUpdateReference, mRecyclerChat);
                //i remove this line of code below, its working but, i feel that this is not the correct
                //chatRoomLastMessageUpdateReference.addChildEventListener(chatRoomLastMessageChildListener);
```

Comment: have you tried with different message may be you have two messages with same text hence same log values ?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure that first one was not printed earlier?

Comment: Yes, i just update logs, where i send 3 messages and as you see, every time its called twice

Comment: I have just update a little bit more my question. On bottom is my update part, please read

Comment: In your `getLastMessage` you also attach a `ChildEventListener`.

Comment: ok how to detach ChildEventListener if i use only the one in getLastMessage()? Will it stay the same detach in onDestroy()?

Comment: Check out my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73677221/7042992 The 2nd trigger in my case was due to ServerValue.TIMESTAMP in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73677221/7042992 The 2nd trigger in my case was due to ServerValue.TIMESTAMP in the data.