# how to retrieve profit of all mobiles from Firebase Realtime database and sum all the values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an application of sale purchase I want to retrieve all the profit of sale mobiles and Sum the values to obtain the total earning.[image]

```
    mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Float> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                list.add(Float.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(ds.child("profit").getValue().toString())));
                double sum = 0.0;
                for (Float d : list) {
                    double floatValue = (double) d.floatValue();
                    Double.isNaN(floatValue);
                    sum += floatValue;
                }
                Toast.makeText(RecordsActivity.this, "Earning = " + sum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(RecordsActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sounds like a clear use-case. Did you try anything already? If so, please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you didn't try anything yet, I'd recommend looking at the Firebase documentation on [handling lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) first.

Comment: i have't done anything yet i just want to know how to fetch all the profit value from every node and simply add them please help i am new to firebase

Comment: check it i have updated the question

Comment: If `mDatabaseReference` points to the `SaleList` node in the database, then that code looks fine at first glance. What's the problem that you have when you run this code? Specifically: if you put a breakpoint on the first line in `onDataChange` and then step through the code, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: i am getting the values from this code thanks the remaining problem is to create an array list for the values and sum all the values to obtain the final result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters I would suggest that you send profits to the database as ints. Then you can find the total sum of the figures under the nodes profits in a data snapshot as shown below

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot 
    dataSnapshot) {
    int sum=0;
    for (DataSnapshot ds1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        int a=ds1.child("profit").getValue(Integer.class);
        sum+=b;
       int i = sum;
      String value = String.valueOf(i);
      Toast.makeText(RecordsActivity.this, value, 
      Toast .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
```

});

Comment: this code is working but why the toast message is continuously changing its value, First time the toast value is true but then it fetch another records .

Comment: This is because you are using addvalueventlistener. Change to add listener for single event value

Comment: Refer to this questions answer for an idea of addListenerforsingleevent....       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304670/ondatachange-is-getting-called-twice-in-android-firebase

Comment: What is happening when you use the addListenerforsingleevent? Is toast still changing value?

Comment: May I please see the code you have used to set the listener

Comment: i have edited my question please check the code above

Comment: i also tried your code mention above but still not working

Comment: The problem was in your code i remove the toast message from the loop and print outside and it works fine

Comment: Oh okay, I assumed you were checking for data change in an onClick method that's why I put the toast in ondatachange